# Spawn away from spawn block that was set by /setworldspawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a custom map and I want to set the world spawn. Whenever use the `/setworldspawn` command, it never spawns me on the correct block. You will see this at play in this short slide show. First I set the spawn, then I kill myself to check it. As you see in the second photo, I don't spawn on the glass block.

SETTING SPAWN:
[image]

SPAWNING:
[image]

Does anybody know of an easy way to fix this?

Comment: Try doing a command that pinpoints the exact location of your spawn. (I think it's  '\setspawn (where you want it to spawn)'). That's because when you set it to where you're standing, it could detect as the block beside you and thus teleporting you up to create a viable spawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
/gamerule spawnRadius 0
```

That should spawn you always on the top block in this x and z coordinate. If you want to be spawned underground, you have to use /spawnpoint for all the players that should be affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

try placing a command block and doing the command (/setworldspawn @a [x] [y] [z]) and putting the command block mode on repeat, then in chat do the command (/gamerule commandBlockOutput false). This should work as it did for me because it is constantly putting the world spawn to that location and the second command means that the command block won't show what it is doing in the chat.

Answer (score -2):

Try doing `/spawnpoint` in the spot you want to respawn.